# Not showing proper result on listview after filtering it

Tags: android, listview, filter, adapter

I have search view which done by using filter method in adapter class so issue is that whenever I am entering the full name or number  for search its not showing result only first item of `ListView` showing  but if I entering first character or number its showing result so I want that whenever I am entering full name or number there should be result, I did debug and I found everything correct in side my code please help.

```
public class AdmitPatientAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> TempArrList = new ArrayList<>();
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    public static final String TAG_MRDNO = "mrd_no";


    public AdmitPatientAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
        activity = a;
        data = d;
        TempArrList.addAll(d);
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }


    public int getCount() {
        return TempArrList.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public void filter(String charText) {
        charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
        TempArrList.clear();
        if (charText.length() == 0) {
            TempArrList.addAll(data);

        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
                HashMap<String, String> tMap;
                tMap = data.get(i);
                if (charText.length() != 0 && tMap.get("mrd_no").toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText)) {//mrd_no
                    TempArrList.add(tMap);
                } else if (charText.length() != 0 && tMap.get("pname").toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText)) {//pname
                    TempArrList.add(tMap);
                }
            }

        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }


    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View viw = convertView;
        if (convertView == null)
            viw = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ip_ptn_items, null);
        TextView txt_Mr_dno = (TextView) viw.findViewById(R.id.txtMrdno);
        TextView txt_pitnt_Name = (TextView) viw.findViewById(R.id.txtpitntName);
        TextView txt_Bed_no = (TextView) viw.findViewById(R.id.txtBedno);
        TextView txt_Dob = (TextView) viw.findViewById(R.id.txtDob);

        TextView txt_drNme = (TextView) viw.findViewById(R.id.txtDr);
        TextView txt_Sex = (TextView) viw.findViewById(R.id.txtSex);
        TextView txt_Wrdnm = (TextView) viw.findViewById(R.id.txtWrdnm);

        HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<String, String>();
        item = data.get(position);
        String mrd_no = item.get(TAG_MRDNO);
        item.put(TAG_MRDNO, mrd_no);
        mrd_no = item.get(TAG_MRDNO);

        if (mrd_no.endsWith("*")) {
            txt_Mr_dno.setTextColor(Color.MAGENTA);
            txt_pitnt_Name.setTextColor(Color.MAGENTA);
            txt_Dob.setTextColor(Color.MAGENTA);
            txt_Sex.setTextColor(Color.MAGENTA);
            txt_Wrdnm.setTextColor(Color.MAGENTA);
            txt_Bed_no.setTextColor(Color.MAGENTA);


        } else {
            txt_Mr_dno.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            txt_pitnt_Name.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            txt_Dob.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            txt_Sex.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            txt_Wrdnm.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            txt_Bed_no.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);

        }

        //Setting all values in listview
        txt_Mr_dno.setText(item.get("mrd_no"));
        txt_pitnt_Name.setText(item.get("pname"));
        txt_Bed_no.setText(item.get("bed_no"));
        txt_Dob.setText(item.get("dob"));
        //txt_admit_Date.setText(item.get("admission_date"));
        txt_Sex.setText(item.get("sex"));
        txt_Wrdnm.setText(item.get("nursingstation"));
        txt_drNme.setText(item.get("doctor"));


        //  item = data.get(position);
        ///  String userType = item.get(TAG_UTYPE);
        //  item.put(TAG_UTYPE, mrd_no);
        //  userType = item.get(TAG_UTYPE);

        try {
            if (item.get("userType").equals("doctor")) {
                txt_drNme.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            } else {
                txt_drNme.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return viw;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code::

Adapter class:

p

```
ublic class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter { 

// Declare Variables 
Context mContext; 



LayoutInflater inflater; 
private List<WorldPopulation> worldpopulationlist = null; 
private ArrayList<WorldPopulation> arraylist; 

public ListViewAdapter(Context context, List<WorldPopulation> worldpopulationlist) { 
mContext = context; 
this.worldpopulationlist = worldpopulationlist; 
inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext); 
this.arraylist = new ArrayList<WorldPopulation>(); 
this.arraylist.addAll(worldpopulationlist); 

} 

public class ViewHolder { 
TextView beamword; 

} 

@Override 
public int getCount() { 
return worldpopulationlist.size(); 
} 

@Override 
public WorldPopulation getItem(int position) { 
return worldpopulationlist.get(position); 
} 

@Override 
public long getItemId(int position) { 
return position; 
} 

public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) { 
final ViewHolder holder; 
if (view == null) { 
holder = new ViewHolder(); 
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_single, null); 
// Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml 
holder.beamword = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textviewitem); 

view.setTag(holder); 
} else { 
holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag(); 
} 
// Set the results into TextViews 
holder.beamword.setText(worldpopulationlist.get(position).getBeamword()); 


return view; 
} 

// Filter Class 
public void filter(String charText) { 
charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()); 
worldpopulationlist.clear(); 
if (charText.length() == 0) { 
worldpopulationlist.addAll(arraylist); 
}  
else  
{ 
for (WorldPopulation wp : arraylist)  
{ 
if (wp.getBeamword().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText))  
{ 
worldpopulationlist.add(wp); 
} 
} 
} 
notifyDataSetChanged(); 
} 

}
```

In your class

```
editsearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() { 

@Override 
public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) { 
// TODO Auto-generated method stub 
String text = editsearch.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()); 
adapter.filter(text); 
} 

@Override 
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, 
int arg2, int arg3) { 
// TODO Auto-generated method stub 
} 

@Override 
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, 
int arg3) { 
// TODO Auto-generated method stub 
} 
});
```

Comment: Found everything correct inside my code I dont think that its good to change code by the way thanks for help